# Need to fix signature not found error MAUI DotNet

Tags: .net, api, maui

I tried to implement a program that needs to display data when I change the date in the date picker in Maui dotnet. but it gives a signature not found error. Couldn't find the solution to it. Can anyone help? The code is below.

```xml
    <DatePicker Grid.Row="3" x:Name="mDatePicker" Style="{StaticResource dateStyle}" MinimumDate="01/01/2020" MaximumDate="12/31/2022" Date="01/01/2022" TextColor="White" DateSelected="Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

```cs
        private void Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         DatePickAync();
        }
    
        public async void DatePickAync()
        {
        
            var client = new RestClient();
            _dateToken = new DateToken();
    
            _dateToken.EmpKy = 874258;
    
            _dateToken.CompanyId = 156;
    
            _dateToken.FDT = new DateTime(2022 - 01 - 10);
        
            _dateToken.TDT = new DateTime(2022 - 01 - 31);
    
            _dateToken.Chk = 0;
    
            _dateToken.PrjKy = 1;
    
            _dateToken.TaskKy = 1;
    
            var request = new RestRequest("https://bl360x.com/BLEComTest/api/HR/MultiAtnAnlysis").AddJsonBody(_dateToken);
    
            request.Method = Method.Post;
    
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    
            request.AddHeader("IntegrationID", "1aa6a39b-5f54-4905-880a-a52733fd6105");
    
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6WyJWaWhhbi5CTCIsIlZpaGFuLkJMIl0sIm5hbWVpZCI6IlZpaGFuLkJMIiwiRmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiVmloYW4uQkwiLCJVc2VySWQiOiJWaWhhbi5CTCIsIkVtYWlsIjoiTm8gRW1haWwiLCJDQ0QiOiJEQyIsInJvbGUiOiJDb21wYW55QXV0aFN1Y2Nlc3MiLCJuYmYiOjE2NzI4OTA1NTUsImV4cCI6MTY3MjkzMzc1NSwiaWF0IjoxNjcyODkwNTU1fQ.dFO70i68Yx7XtglN96vgCPG3-fGNhbrvB_CH3FWQ8XA");
    
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    
            RestResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
    
            // Check the status code of the response
    
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
            // Read the response data
            var responseContent = response.Content.ToString();
    
            Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
    
          }
         else
          {
                Console.WriteLine("Request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
         }
```

Comment: Is this a compiler error or a runtime exception?  Which specific line causes it?  What is the **exact** message?

Comment: This is the error um having......"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XFC0002 EventHandler "Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged" with correct signature not found in type "Attandance_App.Views.Desktop.DesktopStartupPage". Attandance App D:\Industrial\Blue Lotus 360\Assignment\MAUI\Attandance App\Attandance App\Views\Desktop\DesktopStartupPage.xaml 189"

Comment: This is the repo link....and the vihan branch is the updated one until now.... please look after it and give me a solution if you are cable.........  https://github.com/Industrial-BlueLotus/Geo-Attandance.git

Comment: Just put the Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged method and DatePickAync() method in the page.cs.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the [DateSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.datepicker.dateselected?view=net-maui-7.0) event handler should be

```
void Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: Still giving this error....                                                                                                   
                 Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error XFC0002 EventHandler "Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged" with correct signature not found in type "Attandance_App.Views.Desktop.DesktopStartupPage". Attandance App D:\Industrial\Blue Lotus 360\Assignment\MAUI\Attandance App\Attandance App\Views\Desktop\DesktopStartupPage.xaml 189

Comment: Did you fix the event args parameter?  This is a pretty straightforward error.  You can also have VS generate the handler for you from the XAML

Comment: yeah, I changed EventArgs to DateChangedEventArg. But the issue is the same. How can I generate the handler?

Comment: You might try changing it to protected or public.  VS should prompt you to auto generate the event handler when you set the event in the XAML

Comment: I changed it to protected and checked... but still same

Comment: event handlers belong in the code behind.  Commands go in the VM.  Your event handler is defined in the VM, not the code behind

Comment: **"How can I generate the handler?"**. In XAML, delete `="Datepicker_SelectedIndexChanged"`. Type `=` char. Wait. Should get a popup, with first choice something like "create a new handler". Select that choice. Now find where it added the code. As Jason explains, you'll find it in code behind, not in view model. Does that element allow `Command=` property? That can bind to view model.